# How to test that the regression coefficient = 1

Tags: r, regression, hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, econometrics

I'm doing a market model calculation with OLS and I'm using R. I have a sample date with variable Rm and Ri. Its a market model off asset returns as

$$    R_i = \alpha + \beta R_m
$$

I have fitted a linear model, and now I have to run a Market Adjusted return model for $\beta = 1$, using t test statistics with hypothesis as
H0: $\beta$ =1 ;
H1: $\beta$ <>1

Please help how to perform a test that $\beta$ =1

Comment: Did you try `?t.test` and `?lm`?

Comment: In R you could just do `t.test(Rm, Ri - intercept)` where you obtain `intercept` from your linear model

Answer (score 0):

The t-test is implemented in R. For a dataset "x" with columns "y" (continuous) and "x" (binary categorical):

```
t.test(y~x, data, alternative = "two-sided", var.equal = TRUE)
```

You can also display the results of linear models:

```
fit <- lm(y~x, data)
summary(fit)
```

If the regression model is appropriate (e.g., "x" is coded as integer values), it will give similar results as the t-test for β<sub>1</sub>.

Comment: This is not quite correct. The default in R is to do an unequal-variance t-test (Welch year), while the lm linear model will assume equal variances.

Comment: I agree with Dave. Set `var.equal = TRUE`. Also, I would suggest `alternative = “two.sided”` (default) as I don’t think the OP is particularly interested in one side.

Comment: The test is of coefficient = 1 not 0